# C++, Invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’

Tags: c++, string, pointers

In C++ I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string expression_input;
    cout << "User Input: " << endl;
    getline(cin, expression_input);
    expression_input.insert(0, '(');   //error happens here.
    expression_input.append(')');
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
prog.cpp:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’

prog.cpp:15: error:   initializing argument 2 of 
‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, 
_Traits, _Alloc>::insert(typename _Alloc::rebind<_CharT>::other::size_type, 
const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, 
_Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
```

Where am I am converting from `char` to `const char*`?  Can't I insert a character at position 0 of a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know - you're trying to pass a `char` parameter where a `const char *` is required.

You just need to change:

```
expression_input.insert(0,'(');
expression_input.append(')');
```

to:

```
expression_input.insert(0,"(");
expression_input.append(")");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) that takes only a position and a character. What you want is `insert(0, 1, '(')`, which inserts 1 character at position 0.

The same goes for `std::string::append`: `append(1, ')')`

Answer (score 3):

> Now I don't get why does the compiler says I am converting from char to const char*.

The reason you are getting a compilation error is because there is no matching overload for the set of arguments you are passing to the method. The compiler tries to find the closest match, which in your case `char` and `const char*`, and then reports that error.

> Please help me out.

There are 8 overloads for **[std::string::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/)** and 6 overloads for **[std::string::append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)**. You have many different options such as:

```
expression_input.insert(0, "(");
expression_input.append(")");
```

or

```
expression_input.insert(expression_input.begin(), '(');
expression_input.append(")");
```

or even

```
expression_input.insert(0, 1, '(');
expression_input.append(")");
```

There's many possibilities, just choose one that you find most readable or sutiable for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

the version of string::insert function you are using requires const char* you are putting in char use " instead of '

here is a link to method documentation

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

Comment: -1: You most certainly can use `insert` with a `char`. You just have to use a different overload of it.

Comment: i guess i failed to mention that it doesn't work for string::insert function that uses the signature his using